# background image disappears on ipad when changed with jquery

Tags: jquery, ipad

I have a drag and drop educational program that works perfectly on Windows touch tablets and devices.  But when  I access the same program on an iPad, the background image disappears when the image is changed dynamically with jQuery.  Below is the code for one of the functions.  The disappearing back-ground image starts with the four lines that begin "var OldImage = . . .  Same results on old and new iPads with the latest version of iOS.  Thanks in advance!

```
function PasteOld1() {
    animal1.addEventListener('touchmove', function(event) {
        var touch = event.targetTouches[0];
        animal1.style.left = touch.pageX-100 + 'px';
        animal1.style.top = touch.pageY-100 + 'px';
        var p1 = animal1.style.left;
        var xpos = document.getElementById("inputP1");
        xpos.value = p1;
        var p2 = animal1.style.top;
        var ypos = document.getElementById("inputP2");
        ypos.value = p2;
        event.preventDefault();
    }, false);

    var P1 = document.getElementById('inputP1').value;
    P1 = P1.slice(0,3);
    //determines if first touch is image1; if so, copies image url to "old" div>    
    if (P1 > 100 && P1 < 300) {
            var oldImage = $('#animal1').css('background-image');
            oldImage = oldImage.slice(5);// removes first five characters of string
            oldImage = oldImage.substring(0,oldImage.length-2); // removes last two characters of string
            $('#old').css("backgroundImage","url('"+oldImage+"')");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is there a `$(document).ready()` function inside of an if statement? `$(document).ready()` is supposed to fire when the page initially loads, so I don't think binding it within an if statement is going to give you the results you want.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I'm just transitioning from javascript to jquery.  Obviously have a lot to learn.  The program does work seamlessly in a Windows environment.

Comment: I've discovered that the background image is not "disappearing", but for some reason the iPad(ios) is not reading correctly  the new path to the background image (see last line of code.)  And so no background image appears in the div.  If I substitute in an abbreviated version of the path ('media/img/coyote.jpg') the iPad does read it and the background image appears.  I need to have that abbreviated path in a variable and then inserted into that last line of code.  I've tried all of the suggestions for escaping single quotes but nothing has worked for the iPad so far.

Comment: Apparently I was making this task to complicated.  A friend helped me come up with these two simple statements to copy the background-image from one div to another.  It works equally well on an ipad as well as Windows tablets.  var oldImage = $('#animal1').css('background-image');
    $('#old').css('background-image', oldImage);